# How to fix: argument of AND must be type boolean, not type numeric

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to create a summary column (column4), which will contain the total values of column1, column2 if they are not null, and if column3 is null. The theory is pretty simple, however I just cant get it to work.

I have searched stack and could not find an answer that specifically solves this problem.

```
UPDATE table1
SET "column4" = "column1" + "column2"
WHERE "column1" AND "column2" IS NOT NULL 
AND "column3" IS NULL;
```

> ERROR:  argument of AND must be type boolean, not type numeric
>   LINE 4: WHERE "column1" AND "column2...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must repeat the `IS NOT NULL` assertion for column separately:

```
UPDATE table1
SET column4 = column1 + column2
WHERE column1 IS NOT NULL AND column2 IS NOT NULL AND column3 IS NULL;
```

You could try to shorten the above by recognizing that in order for both `column1` and `column2` to be not `NULL`, the sum of these two columns must also be not `NULL`:

```
UPDATE table1
SET column4 = column1 + column2
WHERE (column1 + column2) IS NOT NULL AND column3 IS NULL;
```